# How to mark a socket as unready or used after check it? (C programming with select())

Tags: c, sockets, select, connection

I'm trying to implement an application using select(), but without closing the socket already served and without removing the corrispondent file descriptor from the main set of monitored socket (at least not immediatly). The goal is to create something similar to a set of "persistent connections".

The problem is that after I checked the ready socket, recv() continue to receive the last message a peer sent (running the code below, "Received" is printed infinited times). My thought is that the socket is still "ready", but I can't "mark" it as "unready" or "unchecked" to check it again only if there's a new message from that peer, and close it only in determinate conditions. How can I mark that socket as unready without close it? Is there another solution to implement persistent connections with select()?

Here it is a code of a simple application that I'm trying to program to understand how to realize persistent connections.

Server:

```
int main () {

int ret, sd, new_sd, len, i;
char buffer[1024];

fd_set master;
fd_set read_fds;
int fdmax;

struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

FD_ZERO(&master);
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);

sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port = htons(4257);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

ret = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));
if(ret<0) {
    perror("Error: ");
    exit(1);
}

ret = listen(sd,10);
if(ret<0) {
    perror("Error: ");
    exit(-1);
}

FD_SET(sd, &master);
fdmax = sd;

    for(;;) {
    read_fds = master;
    select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    
    for(i=0; i<=fdmax; i++) { 
        if(FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) {
            if(i == sd) { 
                len = sizeof(cl_addr);
                new_sd = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&cl_addr, &len);

                FD_SET(new_sd, &master);
                
                if(new_sd > fdmax) 
                    fdmax = new_sd;

            }
            else { 

                ret = recv(i, buffer, 4, 0);
                printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                printf("Received.\n");
            
                if(strcmp(buffer, "DEL")==0) { /*Connection is closed only if client request it*/
                    close(i);
                    FD_CLR(i, &master);
                    printf("%d closed.\n",i);
                    continue;
                }       

                len=strlen(buffer);
                ret = send(i, (void*)buffer, len, 0);
                if(ret<0) {
                    printf("socket n%d :\n",i);
                    perror("Error \n");
                }
            
            }

        }

    }

}
close(sd);
return 0;
```

}

I would be really grateful if you would help me, it is very important to me.

Edit: Client side is correct and send only once. "printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));" print always "Success". After the first correct receiving, the program print infinite times these two printf after recv and buffer is empty.

Client:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
int ret, sd, i, len;
char buffer[1024];
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server_addr.sin_addr);

for(;;) {

    scanf("%s",buffer);
    if(strcmp(buffer,"c")==0) {

        sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        ret = connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
        if(ret<0) {
            perror("Error ");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if(strcmp(buffer, "REQ\0")==0) {

        ret = send(sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if(ret<0) {
            perror("Error ");
            exit(1);
        }

        ret = recv(sd, (void*)buffer, 7, 0);
        if(ret<0) {
            perror("Error ");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Received: %s\n", buffer);

    }
    
    if(strcmp(buffer, "DEL\0")==0) {

        ret = send(sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if(ret<0) {
            perror("Error ");
            exit(1);
        }

        close(sd);
        return 0;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You don't have to mark it unready. What is `recv` returning?

Comment: A negative number, printed infinite times. Actually it's a weird behaviour, because in the original code there is another printf after the "if(strcmp(buffer, "DEL")==0)" part and before "len=strlen(buffer);", and that string is never printed...
From the client side, I only send a message "REQ".

Comment: Negative number means error. What does strerror(errno) return when it happens?

Comment: I added "printf("buffer=%s\n",buffer); printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));" and strerror return "Success". Sorry for deleting my last comment: there was a mistake in "printf("buffer=%s\n",buffer);", now I print buffer in the right way. It's not a negative number, but still a number and not "REQ".

Comment: you have to print the error right after it happens, otherwise you're printing the error from `printf("buffer=%s\n", buffer);`. Which number does recv return?

Comment: If I add "close(i); FD_CLR(i, &master);" after the last send(), everything works correctly, so I think the client part is correct...
You are very kind trying to help me! In your opinion what should I do?

Comment: I think you should say what the problem is. What does recv return? If it returns a negative number, what does strerror(errno) say? I think you should describe the situation fully instead of drip-feeding information, because your guess is wrong - you do not need to un-mark sockets after caling select.

Comment: Ok I tried to put "printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));" just after recv, but it returns success. I don't know why, but this time buffer is "REQ" the first time, then it's empty. Always printing infinite times. I swear I only made this change...

Comment: What. Does. `recv`. Return. It cannot return a negative number and then `strerror(erron)` returns success, that is not possible. Either it returns a positive number, or it returns zero, or it returns a negative number and sets the error to something other than success. Those are the options.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you wanted to know the content of errno after putting that instruction in the right position. recv returns 4. I'm really sorry if I can't give you the information you ask for right away, I'm doing my best. And thanks for your patience.

Comment: Okay so the comment you said about negative numbers was wrong... If it returns 4 that means it received 4 new bytes. Since you don't use MSG_PEEK, it really is receiving 4 bytes, different bytes each time, it is not just the same message over and over. So you should look at why the client is sending 4 bytes each time.

Comment: Initially it was buffer that was a negative number. I misunderstood. Sorry again.

Comment: ok, so if for you on the server side the code should be correct, I'll check the client. Thank you.

Comment: Here you go. you should work on this code on geeksforgeeks, not that :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-and-udp-server-using-select

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'll start working on it right away.